# Changing middle mouse button down event to left mouse button double click event

Tags: starcraft-2

Is it possible to simulate a double left click by using the middle mouse button down event?

The reason I'm looking to do this is because it would be a lot easier to single middle button click on a unit to select all units of that type in the visible screen instead of double clicking a unit. I know this seems minor, but I believe it would help me on my micro.

If it's necessary, I have knowledge in several programming languages, but am unsure if it's even necessary to program something.

Comment: Control+Click is easier and does the same thing. Alternatively, you can easily set a macro inside Windows itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decency provides an excellent recommendation for selecting multiple units without external resources. If you insist on achieving exactly what you ask for, you can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com). A sample script which accomplishes this could be:

```
#NoEnv                 ; forwards compatibility
#IfWinActive Starcraft ; only remap for SC
MButton::Click 2       ; remap middle-click to double-click
#IfWinActive           ; reset scope
```

Simply save the above text as a `.ahk` file and open it to enable the script. From then on, whenever you middle-click in Starcraft / Starcraft 2, it'll double-click instead.

Regarding the legality of macros, [this post on the battle.net forums](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2593001680#3) implies that macros that are not used for automation are allowed.